# How can I redirect an incoming URL only if it contains a certain string?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We currently have our company's image hosting site on our own server for the sake of performance. We want to separate the front end of the site (generic pages) from the database-driven backend (where all users upload and view images) so that the front end can be hosted off-site and be enhanced for SEO while the backend stays local on our dedicated server for better performance.

With that in mind, I plan to point the main domain to the offsite hosted pages. Currently our clients have urls pointing to jobs on our server which we cannot change. So, we want to be able to redirect any urls that have a certain string (referring to the backend) to our local server's static IP address.

Example:

- `www.domain.com/aboutus/`   ← Does not contain target string, so no change
- `www.domain.com/TARGETSTRING/something/something/`  ← Has target string, so it will point to our static local IP address, i.e. `http://294.34.21.5/TARGETSTRING/something/something`

One other note: Currently the whole site is running on ColdFusion on IIS. With the new setup, the backend (local server) will stay the same, but the front end will be in Wordpress. So I imagine that the `htaccess` file may come into play, but not with the usual RewriteRule mod.

Comment: does the target string vary or is it static?

Comment: the target string is static.

Comment: @TomW: You are welcome! I hope you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle this in PHP by checking the $_SERVER var that is most applicable.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You can then set a conditional and, if (say a regex pattern match is true) then perform a server-side redirect with `location`.

Comment: I think doing this at the .htaccess level would be a better approach.

Comment: @adamt thanks for the answer. i don't know php so this is all a bit confusing but i will study it and hope i can figure out how to apply what you said.

Comment: @user3783243: do you have a suggestion how to do that? i am familiar with the modrewrite function to redirect all pages to another domain but do you know of a way of being selective based on a static target string?

Comment: You're welcome @TomW . Perhaps the info at this link will help? It's a mod rewrite generator http://www.ipdistance.com/mod_rewrite.php